# cannot boot to Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.10 and run boot-repair

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, boot-repair

I originally had win 7 installed, after installed Ubuntu 12.10, 
I am failed to boot Ubuntu.

I set Ubuntu as my first boot SATA HA

thanks for any suggestions!!!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1534279/

Comment: Please give more details on how you installed Ubuntu. Did you use Wubi? Did you use a liveDVD/ileUSB? Which options did you use? Also, where did you install Grub? Do you have two different hard disks or did you simply partition your existing hard disk?

Comment: To Do : all you ask can be found in the BootInfo URL provided by Michel.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up your BIOS so that it boots your Ubuntu disc (ATA MAXTOR 160GB) instead of your Windows disc (ATA ST31000528AS 1TB).